# AWS Load Balancer whitelist access

Tags: amazon-web-services

So I've read that the AWS load balancer does not use static IPs. I sit behind a firewall which whitelists IPs. What is the best way to set it to allow my AWS LB?

Answer (score 1):

Building the proxy instance with EIP front of the ELB is no good?

It seems there is no way to use the ELB with static IP directly.

Comment: I've not tried building the proxy instance with EIP. What is EIP?

Comment: EIP is "Elastic IP Address", it is static IP mechanism of AWS. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html and read the section "Allocating an Elastic IP Address" and "Associating an Elastic IP Address with a Running Instance".

Comment: Ah i see, I have EIPs to all my instances behind the LB. I did try making a Apache HTTD proxy VM but it always gave 500 errors, so I got rid of that and used an LB instead. is there any other way? Can i put a simple VM with an HTTPS redirect to the LB?

Comment: I have no idea for other way. But, how about using pre-installed squid AMI? If you get 500 errors with those AMI, there is possibility that there is mistake of security groups. http://thecloudmarket.com/search?search_term=squid